# VS Code with "Spring Boot Extension Pack" doesn't finish loading java project

Tags: java, spring, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I am trying to use VSCode as Java dev env.
I have these extension installed.

```
PS C:\shaozr\myworks\sts1\gs-securing-web\initial> code --list-extensions
redhat.java
VisualStudioExptTeam.intellicode-api-usage-examples
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
vmware.vscode-boot-dev-pack
vmware.vscode-spring-boot
vscjava.vscode-gradle
vscjava.vscode-java-debug
vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
vscjava.vscode-java-pack
vscjava.vscode-java-test
vscjava.vscode-maven
vscjava.vscode-spring-boot-dashboard
vscjava.vscode-spring-initializr
PS C:\shaozr\myworks\sts1\gs-securing-web\initial>
```

When I load the sample project from https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ , VS code never finish loading.
[image: VS code never finish loading]

The project itself is totally OK, since I have already run it from Linux.

I checked 'Output' of various 'Task',
I found these output for the 'Git' task , and they just never ends:
[image: Git task never ending]

My question is that:

1. I didn't install 'git extension', where does the 'Git' task come from?
2. How to stop it? ^^

Thanks.